# Is this proof of the error of trapezoidal rule valid?

Tags: numerical-methods

In my numerical analysis lecture notes, the following proof of the error of (simple) trapezoidal rule of $f\in C^2[a,b]$ is presented, based on the error of a linear polynomial interpolation $p$ (with nodes $a,b$):
$$
\begin{align*}
&\quad \int_a^b f(x)\,dx - \frac{1}{2}(b-a)(f(a)+f(b)) \\
&= \int_a^b f(x)-p(x)\, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b f''(\xi_x) (x-a)(x-b)\,dx \\
&\color{red}{= \frac{1}{2}f''(c)\int_a^b (x-a)(x-b)\, dx }\\
&= -\frac{1}{12}f''(c)(b-a)^3
\end{align*}
$$
My question is about the red line (the third equality).
It seems that the author made use of mean value theorem.
However, doesn't this require $\xi_x$ to be continuously chosen?
Technically, $\xi_x$ depends on $x$, so $\xi$ is a function of $x$.
To apply mean value theorem, we then need $f''\circ\xi$ to be continuous.
From the proof of error of polynomial interpolation, I can't really see how $\xi$ can be continuously chosen.
Is it true that the above proof is invalid? If so, is there any easy way to rectify it?

Comment: This seems really really weird. I suggest you look at the proof on Wikipedia, which has appropriate detail and handles the general case of multiple interpolation points

Comment: I just found out that this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819875/error-in-trapezoidal-rule-via-integral-mean-value-theorem?rq=1. My apology.

Comment: You can also write $f(x)-p_2(x)=f[a,b,x](x-a)(x-b)$, so that you have an explicitly continuous function for the mean value theorem. Then for the mean value you get $f[a,b,\xi]=\frac{1}{2!}f''(c)$.